# Induced connection 1-form on orthogonal frame bundle by the Levi-Civita connection on tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, principal-bundles

I recently posted a similar question but I have deleted that one and replaced it with this one, which is hopefully more focused.

On page 317 of [this](https://koreascience.kr/article/JAKO199810736812507.pdf) paper by Pu-Young Kim and Joon-Sik Park they say

> It is well known that, in orthonormal frame bundle $O(M)$
> of a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, the connection form defined by the
> Levi-Civita connection becomes a connection of principal fibre bundle
> $O(M)$.

I could not find a reference for this well known result so I am trying to figure it out on my own.

Suppose $M$ has dimension $n$. The Levi-Civita connection is a connection on $TM$, and $TM$ can be viewed as an associated vector bundle whose fiber is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with structure group $O(n, \mathbb{R})$. I am also familiar with Ehresmann connections on principal bundles, and in this case the principal bundle of interest is the $O(M)$ frame bundle.

I am having trouble connecting the Levi-Civita connection to the associated vector bundle and then connecting that to a connection on the $O(M)$ bundle. So far what I've thought of is that we know every vector bundle has a metric connection, so if we can somehow introduce a torsion-free condition to the associated vector bundle then we will have a Levi-Civita connection which we can hopefully show is unique. But what does this have to do with the Levi-Civita connection on $TM$? And how does all of this induce a Ehresmann connection on the frame bundle $O(M)$?

Comment: Torsion is defined only for the tangent bundle, by the way.

Comment: @TedShifrin In that case how does it make sense to define or associate a Levi-Civita connection on the frame bundle?

Comment: If you do connections with moving frames, it becomes self-evident that a connection (say the Levi-Civita connection) induces a canonical connection on the frame bundle.

Comment: @TedShifrin I have not worked much with moving frames and maybe that is why I am having trouble seeing this result. Do you know of any resource that explains a connection on $TM$ inducing a canonical connection on the frame bundle in detail?

Comment: I’m sure there are plenty of options, but volume 2 of Spivak’s 5-volume differential geometry text will do.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I've never seen it discussed in any textbook I've looked at. Any other suggestions? I'll probably write it up on my blog some day.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, I will try to find a copy of that book.

Comment: @Deane That would be invaluable if you could some day write this up on your blog!

Comment: @Deane all of this is written up (albeit in his typical ‘terse’ fashion) in Dieudonne’s *Treatise on Analysis, Vol IV*, chapter 20 (which is impossible to learn from without Vol III). Section 20.5 in particular covers how a principal connection gives rise to a linear connection in every associated vector bundle, and how conversely a linear connection in a vector bundle gives a principal connection in the frame bundle. Section 20.7 on *G-Structures* then talks about well, G-structures, and in 20.9, he discusses the Levi-Civita connection specifically.

Comment: @peek-a-boo, thanks! I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a metric connection on a smooth vector bundle $E\to M$ equipped with a smooth bundle metric induces a principal $O(n)$-connection on the orthonormal frame bundle $\mathcal O(E)$ and vice versa.
The same is true for arbitrary connections on $E$ and principal $\mathrm{GL}(n)$-connections on the frame bundle $\mathcal F(E)$. Please correct me if something feels wrong.

1. To construct the associated connections, one can choose local sections $s_i:U_i\to\mathcal O(E)$ such that the $U_i$ form an open cover of $M$. Then on the intersections $s_i=s_jf_{ji}$ for unique smooth functions $f_{ji}:U_i\cap U_j\to O(n)$ and the $s_i$  induce local trivializations
   $$
   \psi_i:U_i\times\mathbb R^n\to E_{|U_i},\;\;\;\;(x,v)\mapsto s_i(x)(v)
   $$
   for which the transition functions are given by the maps $f_{ji}$. Now if $\nabla$ is a metric connection on $E$, the pullback connections $(\psi_i)^*\nabla$ on the bundles $U_i\times\mathbb R^n$ can be written as $d+A_i$, where $d$ is the trivial connection and the $A_i$ are $\mathfrak{so}(n)$-valued one form on $U_i$. Then one can show that the $A_i$ satisfy the transition formula
   $$
   A_i = f_{ji}^{-1}df+f_{ji}^{-1}A_jf_{ji}=f_{ji}^{-1}df+\mathrm{Ad}_{f_{ji}^{-1}}(A_j)
   $$
   which is precisely the condition that there exists a principal connection $\omega\in\Omega^1(\mathcal O(E),\mathfrak{so}(n)$) with $s_i^*\omega = A_i$ for all $i$. Conversely for such a principal connection $\omega$, the $A_i:= s_i^*\omega$ satisfy the transition formula from above and then there exists a unique metric connection $\nabla$ on $E$ with $(\psi_i)^*\nabla=d+A_i$ for all $i$. In a similar way there is a correspondence between arbitrary connections on $E$ and principal $\mathrm{GL}(n)$-connections on the frame bundle $\mathcal F(E)$.
2. There is also a nice way to understand this correspondence geometrically, by looking at  the associated parallel transport maps (which determine the connections).  If $\nabla$ is a, say metric, connection on $E$ then a smooth curve $\gamma$ in $M$ connecting two points $x,y$ gives rise to a parallel transport map
   $$
   P_\gamma:E_x\to E_y
   $$
   which is a linear isometry. The fiber $\mathcal O(E_x)$ of the orthonormal frame bundle is the set of all linear isometries $\varphi:\mathbb R^n\to E_x$, where such an isometry is equivalently given by the frame $\varphi(e_1),\dots,\varphi(e_n)$. Then one can show that the corresponding parallel transport map for the induced connection on $\mathcal O(E)$ is given by the left multiplication
   $$
   {\widetilde P}_\gamma:\mathcal O(E_x)\to \mathcal O(E_y),\;\;\;\;\varphi\mapsto P_\gamma\circ\varphi
   $$
   Conversely, if one starts with a connection on $\mathcal O(E)$ and a parallel transport map ${\widetilde P}_\gamma$, the corresponding parallel transport map $P_\gamma:E_x\to E_y$ on $E$ for the induced connection is given by $P_\gamma = {\widetilde P}_\gamma(\varphi)\circ\varphi^{-1} $, where $\varphi:\mathbb R^n\to E_x$ is an arbitrary linear isometry (independent of the choice of $\varphi$, since ${\widetilde P}_\gamma$ is right equivariant).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was very helpful!